# git Pull Same Time & Push different files

Tags: git, push, pull

So i have run into an issue while using git today and it destroyed our development environment.

The issue was we both pulled from development branch at the same time with a co-worker. Then we both made different changes on different files. Then we both pushed at different time. I pushed after him, and his changes were not in the development branch. git didnt warn me before pushing after him as well. His entire work was gone.

Could someone explain me what is wrong here?

Comment: How did you push? If you each pushed different commits, then git would handle merging them. Unless when you pushed it said there were merge conflicts, and you resolved them poorly. Unless your coworker deleted their local branch, they still have their changes and can recover them into the development branch

Comment: i edited files, he added new files, i pushed my commit after him, git didnt warn me about anything it only said "push succesfull"